# Removing block of code from class if condition is met

Tags: c#

What I'm doing is reading a file line by line, and then comparing each line that's read with a pre-specified string.  If it's a match, I want to remove the code from the class I'm inspecting, starting at the line that matched the pre-specified string until a designated location I've identified  is reached.  What I'm struggling with is how to implement a removal.  I've written methods to add, subtract, adjust, etc., but never to just completely remove a chunk of code, so I don't know how to procede.  I bet there's some simple way to accomplish this, but it's escaping me right now.

Comment: @Tim Lehner, you're right it is a duplicate...Although I didn't realize that what I was looking for was just to simply write to another file if a condition was found.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are asking "How do I remove something from the middle of a file?" - it just happens to be source code.

The easiest way is to create a temp file (or in memory stream) to which you write all the content you want to keep and then when you are done processing the old file you over-write it with the contents you choose to keep.

Comment: @Bubbafat--thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  Much appreciated.